# Vigenere cipher-Cryptanalytic attack

Tags: cryptography, vigenere

I implemented a program to break a Vigenere cipher. I've used the algorithm presented on this [site](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-vigenere-cipher/).

**Step 1- Finding the key length:** I suppose that the key length is 2, 3, ..., max key length and I extract substrings for each key length(2 substrings for key length 2, 3 substrings for key length 3 and so on). Each of the extracted substring was ciphered using the Caesar's cipher. Then I compute the index of coincidence for each of the extracted substring for a certain period and then I take the average IC for each period. The period with the biggest average IC represents the Vigenere key length.

**Step2- Finding the key:** Knowing the key length(let us suppose it is n), I extract the n substrings(meaning n Caesar ciphers) from the Vigenere cipher and for each substring I apply a Caesar brute force attack. Then for each string generated by this attack, I compute the chi-squared statistic to find out the key for each Caesar cipher. In the end, the keys for Caesar ciphers will form the Vigenere key.

The problem is that on average only 2/3 of the letters from the Vigenere key are found properly. I want to know if there is something I'm doing wrong. Is there any chance I could get the correct key using this approach?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting together likely possible decryptions and looking for common words: "the" and the like?

Comment: @rossum I'll try that. Thank you!